# How to make angular recognize Nebular Theme

Tags: angular, typescript, web-applications

I have a angular 10 project freshly generated. I added angular nebular theme from akveo, but the themes are not recognized by Angular.

I copied a code example for a card from akveos page but it only shows as a text. I do not get any errors or whatsoever.

This is my code in my opnion I added everything I need in the right places but maybe I am mistaken. Would be nice if someone would look at it.

Angular.json:

```
 ],
            "styles": [
              "apps/moniesta-admin/src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/@nebular/theme/styles/prebuilt/default.css",
              "node_modules/@nebular/theme/styles/prebuilt/dark.css",
              "node_modules/@nebular/theme/styles/prebuilt/corporate.css",
              "node_modules/@nebular/theme/styles/prebuilt/cosmic.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
```

LoginModule(Custom Component):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, 
    RouterModule, 
    NbCardModule, 
    NbThemeModule.forRoot(), 
    NbLayoutModule],
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
  exports: [LoginComponent],
})
```

LoginComponent-html

```
<nb-card status="success">
  <nb-card-header>Nebula</nb-card-header>
  <nb-card-body>
    A nebula is an interstellar cloud of dust, hydrogen, helium and other ionized gases.
    Originally, nebula was a name for any diffuse astronomical object,
    including galaxies beyond the Milky Way.
  </nb-card-body>
  <nb-card-footer>By Wikipedia</nb-card-footer>
</nb-card>
```

Comment: You will probably need to add an import in your scss. Have a look at the docs (first blue box): https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/design-system/enable-customizable-theme#enable-customizable-themes

Comment: Already did that... I imported these ones:

Comment: Also the part under `Enable Nebular Styles`?

Comment: yeah after adding that part I get this error

Comment: I have an NRWL workspace structure btw

Comment: Please update the question (edit the question) to include all the parts you added to the scss files. From your other additions down below it seems though as if you are adding the imports to the wrong files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my scss which login uses:

```
@import '~@nebular/theme/styles/theming';
@import '~@nebular/theme/styles/themes/default';
@import '~@nebular/theme/styles/themes/dark';
@import '~@nebular/theme/styles/themes/cosmic';
@import '~@nebular/theme/styles/themes/corporate';
```